# How fast was the car driving?

Tags: trigonometry

According to this article, http://electrek.co/2016/05/06/tesla-model-s-crash-large-crumple-zone-gallery/ a car flew through the air and landed 25m away. Assuming an ideal ramp angle of 45 degrees, is it possible to determine the car's initial speed, as well as maximum height?

Also assume the ramp is very short, and ends at ground level.

Comment: Need to know how high the ramp is above the ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion

Assuming the top of the ramp was at the same height as the point of impact, we can say that $$d = \frac{v_0^2}{g}*sin(2\theta)$$

where $d$ is horizontal distance traveled, $g$ is the acceleration of gravity at Earth's surface, $v_0$ is the initial speed and $\theta$ is the angle of launch. With $\theta = 45$ degrees, $sin(2\theta) = 1$ and we can rearrange to get $$v_0 = \sqrt {dg}$$

or
$$v_0 = \sqrt{25m*10\frac{m}{s^2}}$$

or $$v_0 \approx 57 km/h$$

which is not very fast at all.

I think the problem here is mostly the assumption that the ramp was at 45 degrees. From the pictures in your link, the ramp looks more like 10 degrees. This would give
$$v_0 \approx 97 km/h$$

**Edit**

I forgot the maximum height. The equation for this is $$h = \frac{v_0^2*sin(\theta)^2}{2g}$$

so just plug in the numbers.